# Publish Transaction Information Type Mismatch Error

Tags: tridion, tridion2009

Using Tridion 2009, SP1, hence the old COM+ TOM API.  I'm trying to get information of a PublishTransaction but getting an error each time I call the PublishTransaction.Information property.

Here is my code:

```cs
try
{
    var pubTrans = (PublishTransaction)tdse.GetObject("tcm:0-166535-66560",
                                                      EnumOpenMode.OpenModeView);
    Console.WriteLine("transaction id=" + pubTrans.ID);
    Console.WriteLine("transaction itemtype=" + pubTrans.itemType.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("transaction info=" + pubTrans.Information);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message, e.StackTrace);
}
```

Above, the transaction ID and Item Type print fine.  I have other code where the Delete method works fine, but any time I try and get the Information, it blows up.

Here is the error:

```xml
<tcm:Error xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" ErrorCode="D"
           Category="18" Source="Kernel" Severity="1">
  <tcm:Line Cause="false" MessageID="16138">
    <![CDATA[Unable to get Information of Unknown (tcm:0-166535-66560).]]>
    <tcm:Token>RESID_4485</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>Information</tcm:Token>
    <tcm:Token>RESID_4663</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>tcm:0-166535-66560</tcm:Token>
  </tcm:Line>
  <tcm:Line ErrorCode="D" Cause="true"><![CDATA[Type mismatch]]></tcm:Line>
  <tcm:Details>
    <tcm:CallStack>
      <tcm:Location>PublishTransaction.Information</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>PublishTransaction.Information</tcm:Location>
    </tcm:CallStack>
  </tcm:Details>
</tcm:Error>
```

I've searched the SDL Tridion World forum and couldn't find the answer.  Am I missing a hotfix, should I contact Support, or is there another way to get the transaction info?

Comment: This same code works fine in 2011 (just tested it). Can't test in 2009 unfortunately...

Comment: What do you get if you use Console.WriteLine("transaction info=" + pubTrans.Information.ToString());

Comment: It blows up the same way.  I haven't had the chance to throw this into the Remote Debugger yet. Got some AD cross domain trust issues to bypass.

Comment: My code snippet from the event system didn't work for you? I saw @SivaCharan's answer was changed into a very similar solution. I was wondering if you got it solved already.

Answer (score 3):

I am not really sure (without digging further at this time of night), but is the 'Information' property actually an XMLElement rather than a string as the docs say? When you use a debugger, are you able to place a watch on this property to see what it contains?

Comment: So I tried this in the debugger.  It's supposed to pubTrasaction.Information is supposed return a string after all.  I couldn't get anywhere past that.  I think this will have to be a support ticket.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this in another way to get the PublishTransaction Information. Below is the code:-

```cs
PublishTransaction pubTrans = (PublishTransaction)tdse.GetObject(
                                                    "tcm:0-4294103-66560",
                                                    EnumOpenMode.OpenModeView, 
                                                    null, 
                                                    XMLReadFilter.XMLReadNull);
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(pubTrans.GetXML(XMLReadFilter.XMLReadAll));
XmlNamespaceManager nameSpace = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nameSpace.AddNamespace("tcm", "http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0");
nameSpace.AddNamespace("xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
Console.WriteLine("transaction id=" + pubTrans.ID); 
Console.WriteLine("transaction itemtype=" + pubTrans.itemType.ToString());
EnumPublishTransactionState transState = pubTrans.get_State();
if (transState == EnumPublishTransactionState.Failed)
  Console.WriteLine("transaction info=" + 
    xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/tcm:PublishTransaction/tcm:Data/tcm:Information",
    nameSpace).InnerText);
```

Comment: The code to load the publish transaction clearly works as ID and ItemType are accessible, so I doubt very much that this is the solution

Comment: Being able to read the ID and ItemType is only evidence that the TOM is able to return to you the values you put in yourself. It's conceivable that this could work OK, yet when it's necessary to go "down through the layers" (to get the Information) a correctly formatted TCM Uri is necessary. Also - using the XML API is a good approach that often works even when there's a problem with the object model.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the missing "tcm" prefix in the question's code.  This actually is just a pasting typo.  I've fixed it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a working environment, so I am just looking into whatever existing code I have available. This is snippet from the Event system which deletes a Queue item only when you have Admin privileges:

```
public void OnPublicationPublishPost(Publication publication, IXMLDOMDocument2 publishResult)
{
    TDSE tdse = Utilities.GetTDSEInstance();
    publishResult.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:tcm=\"http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0\"");
    PublishTransaction publishTransaction = Utilities.GetTridionItem<PublishTransaction>(publishResult.selectSingleNode("/*/*").attributes[2].text, null) as PublishTransaction;
    User user = Utilities.GetTridionItem<User>(publishResult.selectSingleNode("/tcm:PublishResponse/tcm:PublisherRequest/tcm:User").attributes[0].text, null) as User;
    TDSPrivileges isAdmin = user.privileges;
    if (isAdmin != TDSPrivileges.TdsPrivilegeSystemAdministrator)
    {
        publishTransaction.Delete();
    }
}
```